# What is wrong with my namespace friendly XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have read article after article and post after post about how to deal with namespaces. After trying to strip them, include them, and even write my own XML program from scratch in Visual Studio I am just going back to the basics. How in the world do you write XPath for namespaced XML Files?

I am using this site: https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester

Here is the query that I want to make

```
/ExportedObjects/ExportedObject[ObjectValue/@superClasses="Document"]
```

Based on every post regarding documents which contain namespaces I must add extra syntax: `ExportedObjects` becomes `*[name()='ExportedObjects']` and so on for each element.

Well I get this far without issue

```
/*[name()='ExportedObjects']/*[name()='ExportedObject']
```

But when I want to add search criteria, I get no results. Why is it that the namespaced syntax does not work in the where clause?

```
/*[name()='ExportedObjects']/*[name()='ExportedObject']/[*[name()='ObjectValue']/@superClasses="Document"]
```

Example of XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ExportedObjects xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:wn0="http://www.filenet.com/ns/fnce/2006/11/ws/schema" xmlns:wn1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/reference/" xmlns:wn2="http://www.filenet.com/ns/fnce/2006/11/ws/MTOM/schema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.filenet.com/ns/fnce/2006/11/ws/schema">
<ExportedObject><ObjectValue superClasses="Document">Hello World</ObjectValue></ExportedObject></ExportedObjects>
```

Comment: and where is the XML sample you are using?

Comment: It has confidential information in it and it is massive. I can show the header though, with the namespaces

Comment: you can always fabricate an example.

Comment: I created a fabricated example and added to post, showing how I am trying to extract Hello World where the attribute superClasses = "Document"

Comment: works on this site -https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: My example works but the actual document does not. Looks like I am going to have to ask IBM for an example that does not contain confidential data.

Answer (score 0):

Just an educated guess: your XPath is not valid because of a wrong pair of brackets. So it should probably look like

```
/*[name()='ExportedObjects']/*[name()='ExportedObject']/*[name()='ObjectValue' and @superClasses='Document']
```

Maybe this helps you.

Comment: The attribute superClasses is an attribute of the element ObjectValue, not ExportedObject. So this query is incorrect as after AND it says @superClasses='Document'. It should be ObjectValue/@superClasses='Document'] However we can't reference elements directly when namespaces show up, this is the frustration

Comment: IF this is the problem, you should really consider to create a verifiable [mcve]. And if you don't like to disclose your XML, just create a metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Use `local-name()` not `name()`. The result of `name()` includes an unpredictable prefix.

Comment: Same problem, works until I get to the where clause

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't given enough information for me to tell you what you're doing wrong.